# Phone call or contact form?

Tags: user-behavior, user-research

Is there any research into which and why people prefer filling contact forms/writing e-mail to calling by phone?

I want to check my hypothesis that wealth people over 30 y.o. prefer phone call over any contact form

Comment: Where did you get that people prefer filling in forms rather than talking to a person about their issue from? Just curios.

Comment: I didn't get anything. I'm looking for any data connected with the topic

Comment: Oh, ok. It looks in the OP that you're initially stating that people (as a group) would prefer filling in contact forms/writing e-mails rather than calling. I'd rephrase it as "Is there any research done on whether certain groups of people prefer..."

Answer (score 3):

### Income distribution

This [first used contact method table](http://www.fiercegovernmentit.com/pages/income-distribution-people-who-used-other-methods-first-reach-government-agencies-besides-tele) looks like some good research based off the *Government Contact Center Satisfaction Index* - which I think is referring to this: http://www.howto.gov/training/classes/government-contact-center-customer-satisfaction

#### First used other contact method besides phone to reach government agency

```
Income    Yes  No
>$100k    45%  55%
$50-100k  35%  65%
$25-50k   34%  66%
<$25k     38%  62%
```

Indicating likelihood of calling goes **down** with more income - against your hypothesis.

### Age distribution

This [blog post](http://stevensonfinancialmarketing.wordpress.com/2012/06/19/web-is-customers-preferred-way-to-give-business-feedback/) looks at the breakdown of contact for age ranges:

[image]

Which implies that the major shift (increase from 24% call to 35% call) comes around age 45 not 30.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about who and why prefer filling contact forms or calling, I guess it depends of the context (as well as the user). Ex. For ordering a pizza you would use the phone (faster) and for a suggestion/feedback maybe the contact form.

I both cases, I would say that mobile user prefer calling than start filling a contact form from the mobile device. In case of the desktop, writing is more friendly.